# Deep audio fingerprinting for word search

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, natural-language-processing, voice-recognition, audio-processing

Simply speaking, I'm trying to somehow search an audio clip for a list of words, and if found, I mark the time stamps. My use-case is profanity check with a list of pre-defined profane words.

Is there any successfull approaches, samples, tools or APIs, possibly through deep learning, to perform this? I'm new to audio processing.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to perform some kind of `speech-to-text` to get the audio transcription with the corresponding synchronization wrt the audio. Then search in the transcription.

You could use [DSAlign](https://github.com/mozilla/DSAlign) by mozilla